# How can I record video with a Canon 1Dx DSLR which will feed straight into Adobe Premiere or Final Cut?

Tags: software, video-recording, dslr

My university is setting up a video production studio and they want to use a DSLR camera to record videos. However, they want the camera to feed the video into an iMac with Premier or Final Cut installed while it is recording, so I can preview it on the computer screen. Can this be done?

I read somewhere that Premiere and Final cut both use firewire to do this but neither the 1Dx and iMac have firewire inputs. I also read that I can use USB 3 or thunderbolt cable and a Black Magic or AJA box but there are so many products on their sites and I'm confused. Also, the 1Dx only has USB 3 and HDMI outputs.

Please help.

Best Wishes
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Any DSLR that can provide a live video signal (such as via HDMI) can feed that signal to a recording device (such as Atmos SHOGUN) or monitoring device (such as a TV monitor).  In order for your computer to handle live video, you need a live video input port, typically found on cards such as the Blackmagic Design Deck Link card.  BlackMagic's Media Express software can record and/or monitor live video.

I would be surprised if Adobe Premiere Pro (or other NLEs) can handle live video as an editable stream.  But MediaExpress can record with a confidence monitor, and then Premiere Pro can edit the resulting file.

Answer (score 0):

In Final Cut Pro X, you simply connect your camera or card reader to the computer, and choose "Import" and it should show up. There's a [tutorial here](http://www.macworld.com/article/2023824/how-to-use-final-cut-pro-x-with-your-dslr.html).

The documentation for Final Cut Pro X is online. You can read the docs on [file import here](http://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.2/#/verd0e77425).

I've not used Premiere in a few years, so I don't know the workflow there.

Comment: Is is possible to see the footage in Final Cut while the camera is recording, instead of recording first and then importing it?

Comment: I don't know. According to the manual [you can live record from the computer's built-in camera or a connected camera](http://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.2/#/ver41814595). However, I've not tried it with a DSLR. Perhaps if you read that section of the manual it will give you more details.